# how to filter a list of posts based on the search input and display them in a functional component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a functional component which receives a list of posts as props, the goal is to filter the posts based on the userinput from a search field and display the title of the posts. And if no posts found display a message like 'no posts found'. How can i achieve this with functional component and hooks.I am new at React and using functional component and hooks. Thanks is advance.

Each post in list of posts has fields 'id', 'title' and 'body',

My PostsTitleList component

```js
import React from 'react';

function PostTitleList(props) {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');

  // how do i filter the the posts based on if title has the search term and show the title of filtered posts only
  // instead of showing title all the posts

  return (
   <div>
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    <div>
     <input type="text" value={search} onChange={(event) => {setSearch(event.target.value)}}/>
    </div>
    <div>
      {
        props.posts.map(post => (<h3>{post.title}</h3>))
      }
    </div>
   </div>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) to store a state variable for `filteredPosts` which should be initialized with the received props posts, and [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to filter the posts when the value for search field changes.

For example,

```js
function PostTitleList({ posts }) {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("");

  const [filteredPosts, setFilterPosts] = useState(posts);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilterPosts(
      posts.filter(post =>
        post.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }, [search, posts]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Posts</h2>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={search}
          onChange={event => {
            setSearch(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {!filteredPosts.length ? (
          <p>No posts found</p>
        ) : (
          filteredPosts.map(post => <h3>{post.title}</h3>)
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-d2z70?file=/App.js) for demo

Answer (score 0):

```
consts filteredPosts = useMemo(() => props.posts.filter(p => p.title.includes(search)), [props.posts, search])
```

I wrote that without an IDE, but that's the gist. You can get more sophisticated with the search, like lower-casing the search and the titles to make it case-insensitive.

`useMemo` isn't necessary, but it should help with perf a bit if your component re-renders a lot when you're not searching.